# The spyware spooks use to hack mobiles

Tags: phone, surveillance, snooping

With regards to the report and video link below: How do I guard against this sort of snooping? Is it only possible if unwittingly install some kind of trojan?

[BBC Click Report](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-33704157?ocid=socialflow_facebook):

> Surveillance software which can snoop on mobiles, tablets and PCs was
>   stolen from the vendors, Hacking Team, last month.

The attackers published the software on several internet sites making it openly available to download

Answer (score 2):

I find that many cases the device needs some kind of malware installed on it without user knowing:

- Fake malware apps that look like Facebook/twitter,
- Bundling malware within genuine apps,
- Targeted Bluetooth attack,
- Etc.

At some point they would need some type of control software to command over (hence [command and control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_control_%28malware%29)), and yes it is possible.

You need to pay attention on to what you're downloading and using. In most cases phishing rules apply here.

As I am not as coding technical as many others are my answer for you is very policy and common sense based. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am looking for more of a technical answer. Your answer does seem plausible though. Thanks

Comment: @user4702831 I am sure someone could recommend some software or code that might help but I think that there are some standards that could be explained to you on creation of mobile applications. I am not versed in what. Sorry.